# Question about combating contravariance. Callback-related question

Tags: c++, callback, covariance

I have the following piece of code which doesn't compile when I try to instance something like `CommandGlobal<int>` because it tries to override `virtual void Execute() const =0;` with a function which returns `int`. It gives a non-covariance error.

```
class CommandBase
{
public:
    virtual void Execute() const =0;
};

template<class T>
struct CommandGlobal : CommandBase
{
    typedef boost::function<T ()> Command;
    Command comm;

    virtual T Execute() const
    {
        return comm();
    }
};

template<class T>
struct CommandMemberFunction : CommandBase
{
    typedef boost::function<T (int, std::string)> Command;
    Command comm;
    int entityid;
    std::string mfid;

    virtual T Execute() const
    {
        return comm(entityid, mfid);
    }
};
```

I have asked this question before and recieved an answer which I couldn't figure out exactly how to implement. The answer given is as follows:

> Quick & dirty answer: pass to Execute a reference to the result type as a void*, and make Execute private. Then wrap Execute in a non-virtual wrapper which returns T by value and does the cast.

Could anyone clarify this answer with a bit of code. I would appreciate this greatly.

Thanks all!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Your class templates cannot work (except for `T = void`) because the base class has a virtual function returning `void`. You can only override `Execute()` in a derived class by declaring a function with an identical signature, the signature cannot depend on the template parameter in the derived class templates.

Comment: @Charles: Identity is not required, overloading functions are allowed to have covariant return type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think he meant something like (a little bit simplified):

```
class CommandBase
{
private:
    virtual void* ExecuteMe() const =0;
};

template< class T >
struct CommandGlobal : CommandBase
{
    typedef boost::function Command;
    Command comm;
    T Execute() const
    {
         return ((T)(ExecuteMe()));
    }
private:
    virtual void ExecuteMe(void*) const
    {
        return &(comm());
    }
};
template< class T>
struct CommandMemberFunction : CommandBase
{
    typedef boost::function Command;
    Command comm;
    int entityid;
    std::string mfid;

    T Execute() const
    {
         return ((T)(ExecuteMe()));
    }
private:
    virtual void* ExecuteMe() const
    {
        return (void*)&(comm(entityid, mfid));
    }
};
```

Although it's quite error-prone. I'd suggest that you redesign your base interface to have a common interface for T so your Execute() doesn't return void but instead IMyClass or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

I can't figure out how you're going to use this hierarchy. If you are going to do something like this:

```
CommandBase * cb = new CommandGlobal<int>();
```

then what will you put in your code for ??type?? below:

```
??type?? result = cb->Execute();
```

And if your going to do this:

```
CommandGlobal<int> cg;
int result = cg.Execute();
```

then why bother with a base class?

At any rate, you might also look into having Execute return a [Boost.Any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/any.html) instance, as that way both the base class and the subclasses would all be returning instances of the same type. Then you could any_cast the result to the right type at the call site, presuming you could figure out which actual subclass of CommandBase you had.

Comment: I think you are right. I need to rethink my whole approach. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

You need a different name, try something like:

```
class CommandBase
{
public:
    virtual void Execute() const =0;
};

template<class T>
struct CommandGlobal : CommandBase
{
    typedef boost::function<T ()> Command;
    Command comm;

    virtual void Execute() const
    {
        ExecuteWithResult();
    }

    virtual T ExecuteWithResult() const
    {
        return comm();
    }
};
```